# Basic C pointer syntax

Tags: c, pointers, syntax

From what I've seen, the * symbol usually appears before a variable of basic types (eg. int ). However, I've come across a line of code that is as follows:

```
insert(int key, struct node **leaf)
{
    if( *leaf == 0 )
        {
        *leaf = (struct node*) malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
        (*leaf)->key_value = key;
        /* initialize the children to null */
        (*leaf)->left = 0;    
        (*leaf)->right = 0;  
    }
    else if(key < (*leaf)->key_value)
    {
        insert( key, &(*leaf)->left );
    }
    else if(key > (*leaf)->key_value)
    {
        insert( key, &(*leaf)->right );
    }
}
```

How does the * symbol work when it comes before a structure (eg. **struct node***)?

Thanks.

Comment: I recently saw the * symbol in this code: `return 3 * 5;`. I really wonder how *that* worked; as far as I can tell, 5 isn't a pointer.

Comment: Perhaps read any book on c rather than waiting for somebody to type something similar but not so in depth

Comment: I've been searching around the internet (can't afford a textbook right now) for answers. I deeply apologize for wasting your time otherwise.

Comment: I left an answer about what is happening here exactly, but you need to learn and understand the basics of C pointers (declaration, allocation, address of operator &, dereference operator *, etc...)

Comment: Do you not have a library? Or second hand bookshop at the college

Comment: I'll create questions lists and make trips to the campus library and see if I can find information next time. Once again, I'm sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Maybe offtopic, but important: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: You are not wasting my time. You get a better understanding by reading a book and trying things out. Can you not borrow the book for a day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` is both a binary and a unary operator in C and it means different things in different context.

Based on the code you have provided:

```
*leaf = (struct node*) malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
```

Here the `void *` (void pointer) that `malloc` returns is being casted to a pointer to `struct node`, I don't recommend this, for more information read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

I can guess if you see the declaration of leaf it will be like this:

```
struct node ** leaf; //declares a pointer to a pointer of struct node

leaf = malloc(sizeof(struct node *) ); //allocate enough memory for pointer
//remember to not cast malloc in C
```

At this point `*leaf`  is the pointer to `struct node` where the `*` is acting as a dereference operator.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I didn't see that as a type cast, but its very clear that it is now. Cheers for the very helpful explanation!

Answer (score 1):

`leaf` as a pointer to pointer. It means it points to a pointer in memory.
And `*` operator dereferences its operand. So `*leaf` means the value of pointer that `leaf` is pointing to. Actually as I can see this structure is relating to a tree data structure. This code actually allocates memory for where ( a place in memory ) `leaf` is pointing to :

```
*leaf = (struct node*) malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
```

`struct node` is a user-defined type and `struct nod *` means the type of a pointer pointing to a variable of type `struct node`.

Comment: "*`leaf` as a pointer to pointer.*" how do you come to know this? From the code shown is just a pointer, pointer to whatever, the OP does not tell to which type it is pointing.

Comment: It casts the value of where `leaf` pointing to `struct node * ` so `leaf` is `struct node **`

Comment: This is just your assumption, a sane one, yes

Comment: Because we do not see the relevant code. This might be the reason why the question received so many downvotes.

Comment: Yes , but from source he has seen most probably it has been `struct node **`

Comment: "*most probably*" is not necessarily the truth.

Comment: My apologies - yes, the source was a double pointer. I'll edit the OP to include more context.